# Workmanager FCM dependency

Tags: android, firebase, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

We are using a Workmanager library for Android. We are following below prerequisites from Workmanager document.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components

```
// optional - Firebase JobDispatcher support
implementation "android.arch.work:work-firebase:$work_version"
```

Do we need this dependency? Because we are already using FCM core library.

```
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$playServicesVersion") {
        force = true;
    }
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-config:$playServicesVersion") {
        force = true;
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK, that dependency is for `WorkManager` to integrate with Firebase JobDispatcher.

Comment: Ok, Thanks @CommonsWare. I thought JobDispatcher is part of Firebase-core libaray. Looks like that is not included in Google version of Firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I raised the issue with the google developers.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112498866

> WorkManager uses Firebase JobDispatcher if you already have that
>   dependency.  FCM is something different from that - if you don't have
>   Firebase JobDispatcher, you don't need the work-firebase dependency.

So if we don't use JobDispatcher explicitly ([Job Dispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android#user-content-firebase-jobdispatcher-)) we dont need to add this dependency.